# Subset a time-series using matlab

Tags: matlab, time-series

I have a one minute interval time series from which I want to subset 3 columns of data.
The time format is dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss
I want to specify a 20 min time value for which I want to extract the corresponding samples for all the corresponding days (19:00 ; 19:20 ; 19:40 ; 20:00).

I already created a time series using
    ts = timeseries(data, time)
    samples=getdatasamples(ts, i)

But I am having trouble defining the logical vector i that can do such extraction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
pat_19='19:[0 2 4]0:00';
pat_20='20:00:00';
out_19=~(cellfun('isempty',regexpi(a(:,1),pat_19,'match')));
out_20=~(cellfun('isempty',regexpi(a(:,1),pat_20,'match')));
out=a(find(out_19+out_20),:);
```

**Here, I assumed that the value of seconds is always `'0'`**

Please see the example below:

**`"a"` is a cell array with date as first column and data values of time series.**

```
a = 

    '15/08/81 19:00:00'    0.01
    '15/08/81 19:10:00'    0.02
    '15/08/81 19:20:00'    0.03
    '15/08/81 19:30:00'    0.04
    '15/08/81 19:40:00'    0.06
    '15/08/81 19:50:00'    0.07
    '15/08/81 20:00:00'    0.01
    '15/08/81 20:10:00'    0.02
    '15/08/81 20:20:00'    0.03
    '15/08/81 20:30:00'    0.03
```

**after executing the above code, the output is stored in the cell array `"out"`**

```
out = 

    '15/08/81 19:00:00'    0.01
    '15/08/81 19:20:00'    0.03
    '15/08/81 19:40:00'    0.06
    '15/08/81 20:00:00'    0.01
```